Error in Fetching Streaming Response from RetrievalChain javascript
I created the pipeline using langchain inside the JavaScript, when I am using chain.invoke() method its working precisely but when I am trying to call the chain by chain.stream() method I am getting issues as nothing prints on the console. Is there anyone facing the same issues?

    const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
      ["system", systemPrompt],
      new MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
      ["user", "{input}"],
      ["user", userPrompt],
    ]);


    // console.log("Prompt is : ");
    // console.log(prompt);

    // Chain creation using prompt and model
    const chain = await createStuffDocumentsChain({
      llm: modelInstance,
      prompt,
    });


    // Initialize retriever with the vector store
    const startTimeInner = Date.now();
    const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever({
      search_type: "mmr",
      search_kwargs: { k: 3 },
    });


    // console.log(vectorStore);
    const endTimeInner = Date.now();
    console.log(
      "Total time taken by retriever to fetch data from db: ",
      (endTimeInner - startTimeInner) / 1000
    );

    // Create a retrieval chain with the retriever and document chain
    const retrievalChain = await createRetrievalChain({
      retriever,
      combineDocsChain: chain,
    });

calling a streaming response
const response = await chain.stream({
    chat_history: chatHistory,
    input: question,
    
  });
  let firstResponse = false;
  for await (const chunk of response) {
    console.log(chunk);
    yield chunk.answer;
  }


Try using -
chain.astream since you are using await
or try below -
const response = await chain .stream(
{ question: "hello" }, 
{ callbacks: [{ handleLLMNewToken(token: string) 
                  { console.log({ token });}}] }); 
for await (const chunk of stream);


Exception: TypeError: chain.astream is not a function
Getting above error

oh I see - try to use a callback (it will be called for each token) and see what happens.
const response = await chain .stream({ question: "hello" }, {     callbacks: [{         handleLLMNewToken(token: string) {             console.log({ token });         }     }] }); for await (const chunk of stream);

none of the above solutions work for me
